# Regarding crawling urls for Google search appliance

Tags: regex, search, search-engine, google-search-appliance

We have a requirement where we need to crawl one particular set of URLs.

Say for example we have site abc.com. We need to crawl abc.com/test/needed -- all URL matching this pattern under "needed" folder. But we don't want to crawl rest of the URLs under abc.com/test/.

I guess this will be done using RegEx. Can anyone help me with respect to RegEx?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, what do you want? you have a list of urls and you want to match some and not others? which ones do you want to match and which don't you want to match, give examples.

Comment: Say for examples I have following urls          1) www.abc.com  2)www.abc.com /xyz 3) www.abc.com/xyz/imp 4) www.abc.com/xyz/waste 5) www.abc.com/pqr             I am looking for a regex which will find match uls which has pattern "/xyz" but if its "xyz/imp" it shld skip it rest all combinationf or "/xyz" should be matched .

Comment: so you want to match things that are of the form `/xyz` but not of the form `/xyz/imp`?

Comment: I want to match www.abc.com/xyz/imp , www.abc.com/ , www.abc.com/pqr  but not www.abc.com/xyz/waste .

Answer (score 0):

going from what you said in the comment, a pattern to match things of the form `/xyz` but not things of the form `/xyz/imp`:

```
/xyz(/[^i][^m][^p].*)?|/xyz/.{0,2}
```

Comment: Thanks . This is good and is matching url pattern which had xyz .. requirement is bit diff .  I want to match www.abc.com/xyz/imp , www.abc.com/ , www.abc.com/pqr but not www.abc.com/xyz/waste . ... so in short if url has /xyz/ than it should had xyz/imp or else dont match it . if url doesnt have /xyz/ than match those urls as well .

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking for. [here is a tutorial on regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that can be added to the GSA can be:

abc.com/test/needed

or

contains:abc.com/test/needed

The thing to consider is how the GSA will get this documents.  If it can't spider to the folder it won't find the documents.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 specifications that you are allowed to make, in the GSA.

1. Start Crawl URLs -- these tell the GSA where to start looking for links.
2. Follow and crawl only URL patterns -- these tell the GSA which URLs from among those found starting with the "Start Crawl URLs", need to be followed and indexed.
3. Do not crawl URLS -- these are specifications for URLs patterns that match the above 2 patterns, but should not be crawled.

From as much as has been specified in the question itself, I think all you'll need to do is, put in a "Start crawl" url as: "abc.com/" and put in a "Follow and crawl only" specification as: "abc.com/test/needed/", assuming you need no other path/folder on the site crawled.